# Merging a pandas dataframe with a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 pieces of data that I want to merge. 
`df1` is a pandas dataframe that contains a list of contracts, where `year` is the year the contract was was executed, and `o_id` refers to the id of the organization that this contract is from.
`df2` is a pivot table comprised of an organization's problems over the years (where year is the year in which the audit was competed to check for organization problems). `P_1` and `P_2` refer to problem 1 and problem 2.

```
df1

c_id | o_id | year |
====================
101  | 10   | 2013 |
102  | 10   | 2014 |
103  | 10   | 2015 |
103  | 10   | 2016 |
121  | 12   | 2013 |
122  | 12   | 2014 |
123  | 12   | 2015 |
123  | 12   | 2016 |

df2

       P_1                | P_2                 
year | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 |
id   | 
================================================
10   | 1    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
12   | 0    | 1    | 0    | 1    | 1    | 0    |
```

The aim is to merge these two data sets in order to capture the 'history' of problems for each contract relative to the year in which that contract was > executed (merging on `df1['o_id'] = df2['id']`).

Note that I cannot include history for the year in which the contract was executed (e.g. a 2015 contract can only use history from 2014 and before).

I'm looking to make the final output look like this:

```
id | year | 2013_P_1 | 2014_P_1 | 2015_P_1 | 2013_P_2 | 2014_P_2 | 2015_P_2 
===============================================================================
10 | 2013 | NA       | NA       | NA       | NA       | NA       | NA
10 | 2014 | 1        | NA       | NA       | 0        | NA       | NA
10 | 2015 | 1        | 0        | NA       | 0        | 0        | NA    
10 | 2016 | 1        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0    
12 | 2013 | NA       | NA       | NA       | NA       | NA       | NA
12 | 2014 | 0        | NA       | NA       | 1        | NA       | NA
12 | 2015 | 0        | 1        | NA       | 1        | 1        | NA
12 | 2016 | 0        | 1        | 0        | 1        | 1        | 0
```

Comment: Seems a bit redundant to have *year* in long and wide format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reshape `df2` by `stack` and `join` `df1`, then replace values by `NaN`s by custom function:

```
df = (df1.drop('c_id', 1)
        .join(df2.stack(0).reset_index(level=1), on='o_id')
        .set_index(['o_id','year', 'level_1']))

def f(x):
    il1 = np.triu_indices(len(x.columns))
    a = x.values.astype(float)
    a[il1] = np.nan
    x = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=x.columns, index=x.index)
    return (x)

df = df.groupby(['o_id','level_1']).apply(f).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(a,b) for a,b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   o_id  year  2013_P_1  2014_P_1  2015_P_1  2013_P_2  2014_P_2  2015_P_2
0    10  2013       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1    10  2014       1.0       NaN       NaN       0.0       NaN       NaN
2    10  2015       1.0       0.0       NaN       0.0       0.0       NaN
3    10  2016       1.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
4    12  2013       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
5    12  2014       0.0       NaN       NaN       1.0       NaN       NaN
6    12  2015       0.0       1.0       NaN       1.0       1.0       NaN
7    12  2016       0.0       1.0       0.0       1.0       1.0       0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can update your `pivot_table` specification, consider pivoting on a duplicate *Year2* and keep *Year* in index. Then, rename the pivot columns and then run a left join merge:

```
from itertools import product
...

# NEW PIVOT (ADJUST ACCORDINGLY)
origdf['year2'] = origdf['year']
df2 = origdf.pivot_table(index=['ID', 'year'], columns=['problem'], 
                         values=['year2', 'value'], aggfunc='max')

# RETURN CARTESIAN PRODUCT BETWEEN BOTH PIVOT COLUMN LEVELS
newcols = [str(i[1])+'_'+i[0]
           for i in list(product(df2.columns.levels[0], df2.columns.levels[1]))]

# FLATTEN HIERARCHICAL COLUMNS
df2.columns = df2.columns.get_level_values(0)

# REASSIGN COLUMNS
df2.columns = newcols

# RESET MULTI-INDEX BACK AS DF COLUMNS
df2 = df2.reset_index()

# MERGE, DROP UNNEEDED COLS, RE-ORDER COLUMNS
finaldf = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['o_id'], right_on=['id'], how='left')\
                    .drop(columns=['c_id', 'o_id'])[['id','year'] + newcols]
```